# Qual a função do método mágico __wakeup no php?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eu li a documentação, porém não ficou muito claro. `__wakeup()` restabelece a conexão com o banco de dados?

Por exemplo, tenho um script que é executado por bastante tempo, chega uma hora que a conexão com o banco que foi aberta é perdida. Se eu colocar no `__wakeup()` o método que estabelece a conexão, ela será refeita? Se não, como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que tudo, transações, conexão com o DB e etc; estão dentro da mesma classe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com método mágico `__wakeup()` você pode reconstruir objetos serializados através do método [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php). A serialização de objetos é útil quando você precisa transportar objetos para serem executadas em um outro lugar (em filas (*queues*) rodando em outro servidor por exemplo) ou precisa armazenar o estado de um objeto em uma string.

Lembrando que esse método mágicos está em desuso em favor da interface [`Serializable`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.serializable.php) presente desde o PHP 5.1.

Veja um exemplo de como implementar a interface `Serializable`:

```
<?php
class obj implements Serializable {
    private $data;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = "My private data";
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->data);
    }
    public function unserialize($data) {
        $this->data = unserialize($data);
    }
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$obj = new obj;
$ser = serialize($obj);

var_dump($ser);

$newobj = unserialize($ser);

var_dump($newobj->getData());
```

O retorno será:

> string(38) "C:3:"obj":23:{s:15:"My private data";}"
>
> string(15) "My private data"

<sup><sup>Código extraído da documentação.</sup></sup>

> Por exemplo, tenho um script que é executado por bastante tempo, chega
>   uma hora que a conexão com o banco que foi aberta é perdida. Se eu
>   colocar no `__wakeup()` o método que estabelece a conexão, ela será
>   refeita?  Se não, como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que tudo, transações, conexão com o DB e etc; estão dentro da mesma classe.

Esses método mágico não funciona dessa forma. Nesse caso você pode capturar algum tipo de `Exception` e dar um *retry* na conexão sem precisar serializar um objeto por exemplo. Provavelmente você perderá informações de *transactions* nesse caso.